# JPos application error

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, motorola, jpos

Hi I am trying to debug the jpostest application that came with Motorola Scanner SDK foe Windows.

I am using Eclipse (Juno) with Java 7 on Windows 8.

I get the following exception when I click on the 'open' button in the 'Scanner' tab of the 
POSTest application.

jpos.JposException: Could not connect to service with logicalName = MotorolaScannerSNAPI: Exception.message=com.symbol.jpos.SymScannerSvc112Factory
org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a bit late, but it seems that you are missing some 'jar' dependencies.

In the 'JPos Sample Application' folder of the Motorola Scanner SDK, check the 'JPosTest.bat' file, it lists all the needed dependencies (by defining some classpaths). You will also need to define the 'java.library.path' property to point to the directory containing the CSJPOS.dll (it is also done in the bat launcher).

Comment: Yes, Bastien you are right, this means a jar file containing this path:"com.symbol.jpos.SymScannerSvc112Factory" is not loaded. Hope this link can help more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241087/jpos-configuration-problems-for-an-epson-pos-printer-in-windows/59526503#59526503